Command line autocompletion for a custom script
In the command line of a Linux terminal, I want to run a custom, say, bash script that needs a parameter a file name, stored in any given directory. Can the script be programmed to autocomplete with those file names?
Example of <my_script> prepared to receive an argument, as a file name from <any_directory>:
$ my_script [TAB][TAB]
$ 01_file
$ 02_file
...
$ N_file
$ my_script 0[TAB][TAB]
$ 01_file
$ 02_file
...
$ 09_file

where these are files stored in <any_directory>.

Have a look at https://github.com/scop/bash-completion
